# override a django third party application settings

Tags: django

I am using a third party django application. I would like to override the application middleware and especially some values in its settings file. How could I do this in a separate place. It is not possible to import the installed app settings into my project settings. Thanks.

Comment: Apps don't usually *have* their own settings...

Comment: in fact it is a conf.py file which holds a variable settings: settings = SettingsProxy(django_settings, defaults) Somewhere in the middleware I have from django_mobile.conf import settings. What I want is to change some values from this conf file

Comment: And you can't override them in the project settings like normal?